# How to call function after leaving the particular input

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have 2 inputs, I wanted to call a function after switching to second input. I tried it by `ng-change` but that will call function on each value.

Can any one suggest me how to call a function after switching to next input.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/27028/)

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText1"  size="30" placeholder="add new todo here"><br>

          <input type="text" ng-model="todoText2"  size="30" placeholder="add new todo here"><br>


  <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call function on ng-blur if you want to call function as soon as you leave the field
or you can call function on ng-focus of next input if you want to call function as soon as you switch to next field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="todoText1"  size="30"
     placeholder="add new todo here" ng-blur ="myfunction()">

<input type="text" ng-model="todoText2"  size="30"
     placeholder="add new todo here" ng-focus ="myfunction()">
```

From this two i will choose ng-blur because many time i found performance issue on ng-focus

Answer (score 2):

You can add the [`ngBlur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) and call the function

```
<input type="text" id="exampleab"  ng-blur="showValues()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right you can do this on focus event of second input with *jquery* like this:

```
$(function(){
     $("[ng-model='todoText2']").focus(function(){
         // call your function
    })
})
```